# Can swing worker help improve performane with lazy loading jtree - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtree

i am new java swing guy. I am doing a project using lazy loading to improve the performance of my app. You can reference to [Tree-Will-Expand Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/treewillexpandlistener.html) and [TreeExpandEventDemo2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/TreeExpandEventDemo2Project/src/events/TreeExpandEventDemo2.java). My issue is i don't handle tree will expand event instead of i use tree selection event. Cause i think the node user choose don't know that i could epxand ( i mean the node don't have the expanding symbol).
i put my code below here:

```
tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {

            switch (clickTreeNode( e)){
                  case EXPAND:
                    treeValueChanged(e);
                    TreePath path = tree.getSelectionPath();
                    if (path != null) {
                        Object obj = path.getLastPathComponent();
                        if (obj instanceof Vertex) {

                            List<CustomMutableTreeNode> result = new ArrayList<>();

                            AbstractNode node = ((Vertex) obj).getUserObject();

                                node.getChildren().forEach(child -> {
                                    Vertex v = new Vertex((Vertex) obj, child);
                                    result.add(v);

                                });

                                CustomTreeModel treeModel = (CustomTreeModel) tree.getModel();

                                treeModel.lazyLoadingChildren(result);
                                treeModel.reload();
                                tree.expandPath(path);
                            }
                        }
                        break; 

                    case SELECT:
                     treeValueChanged(e);
                     break;

                     }
              }
        });
```

My lazy loading function here:

```
public void lazyLoadingChildren(List<CustomMutableTreeNode> nodes){

    nodes.stream().forEach(node -> {          
        if (node instanceof FundamentalGraphUnit) {
            if (node instanceof IShell) {
                CustomMutableTreeNode parent = node.getImmutableParent();
                if (node instanceof EdgeShell && parent.getParent() == null) {
                    super.insertNodeInto(parent, parent.getImmutableParent(), 0);
                }
                super.insertNodeInto(node, parent, parent.getChildCount());
            } else {
                reload(node);
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Is there anyways to separate the treewillexpand and selection event. Can swing worker can improve the performane ( I have 4 layers, the total number of nodes is more than 100000). Thanks for your help.